# Looping through nested json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a badly designed JSON object which unfortunately I cannot change at this moment which contains a number of objects. Here is an example of what I am working with:

```
var land = [
    {"name":"city","value":"Los Angeles"},
    {"name":"state","value":"California"},
    {"name":"zip","value":"45434"},
    {"name":"country","value":"USA"}
];
```

Here is how I am looping through i:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each(land, function(key,value) {
      $.each(value, function(key,value) {
          console.log(key + ' : ' + value);
      })
    }); 
})
```

The result is as follows:

```
name : city
value : Los Angeles
name : state
value : California
name : zip
value : 45434
name : country
value : USA
```

My goal is to have a result like this:

```
city : Los Angeles
state : California
zip : 45434
country: USA
```

What am I missing here? How do I achieve my intended result? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: FYI: You do not have a "JSON object." There's no such thing as a "JSON object." It's a widespread misnomer. JSON is a text format. What you have is an array of objects. Not JSON, just objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using ecmascript 5's forEach method:

```
land.forEach(function(entry){ 
      console.log(entry.name + " : " + entry.value) 
} );
```

or use jquery to support legacy web browsers:

```
$.each(land,function(index,entry) {
     console.log(entry.name + " : " + entry.value)
});
```

Comment: I tested the second, jquery approach works like a charm :)

Answer (score 4):

Don't loop through the subobject, just show its properties.

```js
var land = [{
  "name": "city",
  "value": "Los Angeles"
}, {
  "name": "state",
  "value": "California"
}, {
  "name": "zip",
  "value": "45434"
}, {
  "name": "country",
  "value": "USA"
}];

$.each(land, function(index, object) {
    console.log(object.name, ": ", object.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tested the code and it works. Now I have to figure out where I was going wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

If property names are same in all object(`name` and `value`) then do it like.

```
$.each(land, function(key,value) {
  console.log(value.name + ' : ' + value.value);
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm sir. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You only need one `forEach()` loop to get this result.

```js
var land = [{
  "name": "city",
  "value": "Los Angeles"
}, {
  "name": "state",
  "value": "California"
}, {
  "name": "zip",
  "value": "45434"
}, {
  "name": "country",
  "value": "USA"
}];

land.forEach(function(e) {
  console.log(e.name + ' : ' + e.value);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tested the code and it works. Now I have to figure out where I was going wrong in the first place.

Comment: Why jQuery (OP never mentioned it) where the solution can be achieved with vanilla JS?

Answer (score 2):

Don't iterate through objects. You need only single loop to achieve this.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
                $.each(land, function(key,value) {
                      console.log(value.name + ' : ' + value.value);
                }); 
            })
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tested the code and it works. Now I have to figure out where I was going wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
var converter = function(object){
    return {city: object[0].value,
           state: object[1].value,
           zip: object[2].value,
           country: object[3].value
    }
}

converter(land)
```

Object { city: "Los Angeles", state: "California", zip: "45434", country: "USA" }

Comment: Although it is a great way to convert it, I have hundreds of db records that I need to loop through so I would have to convert all of them, and then loop.